# Pandas - Dtype is int but when I use describe() or do data visualization it becomes float?

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I have a pandas dataframe which has a population column and it seems like it is integer.

```
    df.info()
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 274 entries, 3792 to 4065
    Data columns (total 5 columns):
    #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
   ---  ------       --------------  ----- 
    0   ID           274 non-null    int64 
    1   Name         274 non-null    object
    2   CountryCode  274 non-null    object
    3   District     274 non-null    object
    4   Population   274 non-null    int64 
    dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
    memory usage: 20.9+ KB

    df.head()

    ID       Name      CountryCode     District               Population
    3793    New York     USA            New York                8008278
    3794    Los Angeles  USA            California              3694820
    3795    Chicago      USA            Illinois                2896016
    3796    Houston      USA            Texas                   1953631
    3797    Philadelphia USA            Pennsylvania            1517550
```

However, when I use describe() or boxplot it seems as if it is float.

```
    df.describe()
                 ID      Population
    count  274.000000   2.740000e+02
    mean   3929.500000  2.869554e+05
    std    79.241193    5.865830e+05
    min    3793.000000  8.906300e+04
    25%    3861.250000  1.117355e+05
    50%    3929.500000  1.497940e+05
    75%    3997.750000  2.462355e+05
    max    4066.000000  8.008278e+06
```

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgkZH.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly, look into your dataset manually and see exactly what it is. If you would like to convert these actually to integers, you can use `df["ID"] = df["ID"].astype(int)` or you can manually round it how you like.

Comment: It is not a float. It's a scientific notation of numbers. `2.74e+02 = 274` and `8.008e+06 = 8,008,000`. And as for the boxplot, The scale is `1e6`, so `1` on the plot is actually `1,000,000`.